# Text in 'stairs' layout by CSS or Javascript?

Tags: html, css, layout, text

I'm trying to achieve with kind of layout inhtml/css/jquery (see attach file)

[image]

Does anybody have any idea how this can be done ? I tried to put a css shape or svg for the line - which is fine, but how to make the text going this format ? Any highlight would be incredible, From my research I can't find any information like that ! thank you foe your time :)

EDIT: what about this format ?

[image]

Comment: are you ok with a JS solution for this?  Do you know the width and height of the stair shape there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility in JS.  It basically amounts to inserting floated divs of increasing widths, each one line-height high (I colored the divs red to make it more obvious).  You could do this straight in the HTML if you wanted too.

```js
var stairsHeight = 500;
var lineHeight = 20;
for (var y = lineHeight; y <= stairsHeight; y+=lineHeight) {
 $(".stairs").prepend('<div style="height:' + lineHeight + 'px; width:' + y + 'px; float:right; clear:right; background:red;"></div>');
}
```

```css
.stairs {width:500px; height:500px; line-height:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stairs">
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
</div>
```

Comment: thats looking good, thank you so much !

One trick, is it possible to have the left align justify like it now, but that after a while both side ( left and right) of the text get the same 'stairs effect' ?

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Sure, just play around with floating some divs left as well as right.  You can do any kind of diagonal shape with this method.

Comment: Hm, I tried to add another class inside with a float left for the new one, but it doenst seem to work :( Do you have an example by any chance : ?

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much, there is a last layout i trying to achieve, I've just update my questions  and adding a screenshot. It's like a align right with stairs effect on the left, follows by a left-align on stairs on the right.

Do you have any idea how to achieve it ? I ve been stuck on it since few days.

Thank so much !!

Comment: and add a ` text-align:justify;` to even it out on the right side, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tutorial: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/ .
With such non-standard shape key is `polygon()` for either shape-inside or shape-outside . They really did nice illustration so it's easy to understand and apply to your own ideas.

Comment: cool, but pretty crappy browser support for it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

Answer (score 1):

## Css shapes

What you are looking for is called the `shape-outside` css property.

Currently only chrome supports this feature.

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)

And if you are wondering on how to use it:

```css
.element {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 100px, 100px 100px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100px, 100px 100px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
span {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">

</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar si amet Lorem ipsum
  <br>dolar si amet Lorem ipsum
  <br>dolar si amet Lorem ipsum dolar si amet Lorem ipsum dolar si amet Lorem ipsum dolar si amet Lorem ipsum dolar si amet</p>
```

[Css shapes tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a png but most definitely it's a canvas, you can draw any shapes using canvas with lineTo x, y coordinates, it uses javascript but even if you are not good with javascript there are really good sources around
You can try it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_path

Comment: I sent him a link to the editor, just to get the main idea and maybe try it in the editor or something. I totally agree that it's not a good source.