# Wrap text in stairs with css

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and wonder, is it possible to achieve text wrapping in custom way with css. Let say I have report with 6 columns. Each column has its own alignment and initial state of report is:

```
|| col1 centered || col2 centered ||col3 left align   ||    col4 right||
```

After resize of browser, narrowing it, first column overflows second and wrap occurs:

```
||  col1 centered
||          col2 centered ||col3 left align    ||      col4 right||
```

Further, narrowing a bit more, text in third column overlaps text in rightmost column and it forces fourth column to wrap like this:

```
||  col1 centered
||          col2 centered ||col3 left align 
||                                      col4 right align ||
```

At the end, when browser could not be narrowed more, wrapped string is wrapped in stairs where each step is text of certain initial column and report looks like this:

```
|| col1 centered
||     col2 centered
||          col3 left align
||               col4 right align
```

I tried to play with blocks, inline-blocks but could not achieve wrap in a stairs way. What css methods / objects are most appropriate to achieve wrap in stairs like described above ?

Comment: This looks like it will answer your question..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490161/text-in-stairs-layout-by-css-or-javascript

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611964/8620333

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text in 'stairs' layout by CSS or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490161/text-in-stairs-layout-by-css-or-javascript)

Comment: I see suggested link before posting question, in my case I look for something like several inline-block on the same line with different text alignment inside each inside-block, and after wrap each inline-block goes one line down retaining its relative offset from left of page. Use of JavaScript is by default a solution for question, but may be there is pure css solution ?